# Compile code to multiple directories in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, templates, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to make a simple template for driver so that I can write drivers quickly, however, I was wondering if it's possible to compile code in different directories. For instance, I want to compile for all OS's (WinXP, Win Vista, Win7 etc.) in different directories?

Comment: Create different configurations in the project and select output directory for every configuration, like Debug_W7, Release_W7 etc.

Comment: That's quite clever. Don't know why I didn't remember of that, I'll try that and see how it goes !